# Mac OS replace ';' with new line on text file

Tags: macos, text-editor

Really basic question I'm sure for the normal Mac user but;

I'm a very recent Mac convert and I want to do a quick operation on a file.  I would normally do this in windows by doing a search for ';' and replace with '\n' in my favourite editor(Editplus) but this doesn't seem to work on the two editors I have installed (Coda, Espresso) on my mac.   I have other ways of doing this but I figured it would be better if I understood why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I guess you have problems entering the replace string in the find dialog. If you want to enter a newline in any single line Cocoa text field, you have to press ⎇⃣⏎⃣ (alt return). Also works for tab.

Comment: Ba bam...this worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

You can do this on the command line in the **Terminal** with:

```
cat input | tr ";" "\n"  > output
```

**cat** prints the content of the file *input*, **tr** takes this output and replaces **;** with **\n** and this is then written into the file *output*